# Click event firing only once for increment function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events, onclick

The first `if` condition is working as desired multiple times but the second and third condition run only once. if the `fa-plus-square` element is clicked then the number increases only once and the minus element decrements only once. Why doesn't it increase further?

```js
let input = document.querySelector(".quantity-input");
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('quantity-input')) {
    input.value = 1;
  }
  if (e.target.classList.contains('fa-plus-square')) {
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
  }
  if (e.target.classList.contains('fa-minus-square')) {
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) - 1;
  }
});
```

```html
<p class="quantity">
  <span class="quantity-text">Quantity </span><i class="far fa-minus-square quantity-icon">-</i>
  <input type="number" value="1" class="quantity-input" />
  <i class="far fa-plus-square quantity-icon">+</i>
</p>
```

Comment: Hi, i am not sure to understand, you ask guy to click on document and you looking for classlist of the document?

Comment: If you click on `.fa-plus-square` that element does ***not*** contain the class `.quantity-input`. So, the first thing your listener does is set the value to 1. Then it increases it by one.

Comment: @DafuQi `e.target` is the element that was clicked on, not the element that the event listener was added to. This is event delegation.

Comment: He still put the listener in his entire page to check only for things in "id: quantity" tag? @Barmar

Comment: @DafuQi Yes, it's a bit excessive, but it works.

Comment: @Barmar he need to scope for the input.value right? i guess with the actual code he is using something that don't exist, but i might be bad there

Comment: So, how do I fix it so that it can further be increased more than once?

Comment: @DafuQi No, read my comment. The first `if` fires before the second one does. So the value goes `1` -> `1` -> `2` the first time. Any next click the value goes `2` -> `1` -> `2`

Comment: @DafuQi He wants clicking anywhere else to reset the input to 1.

Comment: @Barmar oh thats a weird way to use an up/down but ok, thanks for making a code for him, have a good day guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check for the plus and minus buttons first, and use `else if` so you only test for not clicking on the input field if neither of those succeeds.

Otherwise, when you click on the plus or minus buttons, the `!e.target.classList.contains('quantity-input')` condition is true, so it sets the input back to 1 before adding or subtracting.

```js
let input = document.querySelector(".quantity-input");
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('fa-plus-square')) {
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
  }
  else if (e.target.classList.contains('fa-minus-square')) {
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) - 1;
  }
  else if (!e.target.classList.contains('quantity-input')) {
    input.value = 1;
  }
});
```

```html
<p class="quantity">
  <span class="quantity-text">Quantity </span><i class="far fa-minus-square quantity-icon">-</i>
  <input type="number" value="1" class="quantity-input" />
  <i class="far fa-plus-square quantity-icon">+</i>
</p>
```

Comment: Also possible - add `.quantity-input` to the +/- buttons, so they are exempt from the reset functionality. The selector for the input might need to be changed to `input.quantity-input`

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I just had to shift the first condition to the last in my code :)